# how to add a dynamic body class based on URL structure?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, redirect

I built a static `HTML` site for a friend who's renting his condo. When brokers link to his site, he needs his email address hidden in the footer, but otherwise visible.

The solution would be to target those unique inbound URLs and hide the email address with `CSS`, but he's said there might be dozens of brokers and in some cases we might not know their URLs.

I'm wondering if to create an alternate URL somehow. Ex: `www.myislandvilla.com/?=nocontact`, and somehow adds a `<body>` class, which will allow me to target with CSS?

Comment: If your server is running PHP or JSP it could be easy to do server-side using alternate URL.

Answer (score 0):

Condidering the URL is www.myislandvilla.com/?spe=nocontact

You've got two options :

- if your server is running PHP or any dynamic language, you can easily set a condition on the element (i.e. a div) you want to hide. For instance, in PHP :

  if($_GET['spe'] == 'nocontact') { echo 'style="display: none;"'; }
- if your server is not running PHP, you can always use Javascript (see this question on how to get the query string: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)) and hide the element if the query string matches.